# C++ class design: member and local variables

Tags: c++, class, variables, class-design

Is there any difference between the following two examples and should one be preferred over the oher:

Example 1:

```
class A
{
    int i;
    B* b;

    do_something();
    do_something_else();
}

A::do_something()
{    
    do_something_else();
}
```

Example 2:

```
class A
{
    int i;

    do_something()
    do_something_else(B* b)
}

A::do_something()
{
    B* b;
    do_something_else(b);
}
```

Now let's say there are several methods using `b` is it better to have them all take it as an argument or take no arguments and use a member variable? Is there a difference in performance between the two approaches? I can see the benefits of both, but which one would be preferred?

Comment: You said you could see the benefit of 'both'. Could you mention them?

Comment: Yeah, with local variables you'll have a smaller class and it will be easier to see what the methods do by looking at their declarations. Also it will be possible to make methods public and use them from other classes. With member variable you'll have it easier to access it from anywhere inside the class and also be able to access it from other classes if necessary. Now, why is this question being down voted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This really comes down to how your object model fits together and whether an aggregation relationship accurately represents what you are hoping to model.

Think about whether `B` in your case truly exhibits a *has-a* relationship with `A` (i.e. is it true to say that `A` *has-a* `B`?) For example, in most cases, a car *has an* engine, so an engine could reasonably be owned / contained by a car. If this is the case then you should probably go with example 1.

If on the other hand there is no direct relationship but `A` just needs to act on another object without owning it or containing it then you should stick with example 2. For example:

```
Dog myDog;
Stick aStick;
myDog.fetches(aStick);
```

clearly a stick is (hopefully) not an integral part of a dog.

It is tempting to incorporate variables (especially pointers) into the class for expediency and to make code look nicer (i.e. because you don't have to pass so many parameters,) but if the contained object does not have a strong relationship with the container and / or is managed somewhere else, you very frequently get into complex lifecycle management issues which can counter the very benefits you sought to gain from aggregation in the first place.

Answer (score 12):

Make variables members if they belong to the object you are designing. If you are working just with temporary variables - do not make them members, because in that case you will just pollute your object design

Answer (score 3):

The one that fits is preferred.

If class instance should *own* the object the pointer is pointing to, then it should be member variable. If it's just parameter for functions, **not intended to be owned by the object**, then don't make it member.

Answer (score 2):

**Use aggregation/composition (holding variables as members) because you need to maintain state, between function calls**

While the advices which concern the object model are sound, very often you stumble upon cases where you have pure-fabrication classes, and the "has-a" and "is-a" doesn't really make sense anymore.

If you continuously disregard this advice it will have a price.

- **The object size get larger**, this will affect you memory wise and performance wise when you choose to copy your object.
- **You communicate that the member is a part of the object state**, meaning that other developers (remember you are also an "other developer" in a couple of weeks) get confused when trying to find out how this object is a part of the objects state.
- **You need to know the member size in the header**, this is an extra include in your header file, keep up that practice and you will be compiling for weeks when you change a single line in a basic header. You only want a minimal number of includes in your headers.

So do *not* use this technique to cut down on the number of arguments. (and remember that there are no absolute truths)